# Channel receives data, does not do anything with it

Tags: go

I'm reading user inputs through a function using Scanf, and passing the cli inputs to a chennel.

Then, I have a main loop that ticks every second. In the main loop, I'm waiting for user inputs and I parse them accordingly.

Comment: Basically everything with your select is wrong: 1) Its a busy wait, 2)  the two value 
 form `selection, _ := <-userInput` in select is nonsensical, 3) you should just `range` over userInput. Redo the Tour of Go, starting maybe at  https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/4

Comment: Not related to your question, but what is an "mp3 player simulator"?  A program that pretends to play MP3s, but doesn't really?

Comment: @Volker it's not a busy wait, the `select` is only one part of the loop body, which includes a sleep.

Comment: @Adrian You are right. Unfortunately is is still wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Range over the channel. There's no need to sleep:

```
func PlaySong(sec int, status chan string) {
    userInput := make(chan string)
    go PlayControl(userInput)
    paused := false
    for selection := range userInput {
        if selection == "p" {
            paused = !paused
        } else if selection == "s" {
            fmt.Println("Stopping song")
            break timeloop
        }
    }
    status <- "done"
}
```

To make `PlaySong` exit the range loop when the user types `ctl+D`, close the input channel when PlayControl exits.

```
func PlayControl(input chan string) {
    defer close(input)
    for {
        var s string
        _, err := fmt.Scanf("%s\n", &s)
        if err != nil {
            break
        }
        fmt.Println("input recieved: " + s)
        input <- s
    }
}
```